# How can I replicate the following excel calculations in SQL statements ?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, oracle

I start with columns `Week` , `Prod` and `Qty`:

[image: Initial Dataset]

I'd like my output to be the following :

[image: Desired output]

I have used the following excel formulas to get this output:

In Cell D2 : `=IF(B2=B1, IF(C2=C1, "N", "Y"), "N")`
In Cell E2 : `=IF(D2="N", "NA", C2-C1)`

I'd like to replicate the same in SQL statements. I'm not sure how I can get started.

Comment: Are you asking about Oracle DB specific solution, MySQL specific solution, or a general SQL solution? What's the actual problem you are trying to solve (i.e. SQL experts do not need to be Excel experts)? Is the value in column "A" significant or not (i.e. what if I changed values in there, without changing others - the formulas suggest, that "D" and "E" should not change in such case)?

Comment: Your formulas rely on data ordering (as formulas are based on data from more than one row), while relational DBs do not order table data. What defines your data order?

Comment: I need a generic SQL solution. I am writing the SQL code in DBeaver. Also, yes, my formulas rely on data ordering. The table has been sorted on 'Prod' and 'Week' and then the formulas have been applied. I thought I could use "ORDER BY" in my SQL code to do the same.

Comment: You're looking for `LAG()` - which is only supported in [recent versions of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html).

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are trying to compare the quantity of each given product over consecutive weeks. In SQL, you can achieve this by joining the table with itself, using a `LEFT JOIN` clause (same product and next week). When there is no match (no next week for the given product), the join clause will yield NULL values. Based on this, you can then implement the comparison logic.

You tagged your question with both `oracle` and `mysql`, I don't know if it's really on purpose, but this solution should work for both :

```
select
    t1.week,
    t1.prod,
    t1.qty,
    case 
        when t2.week is null or t1.qty = t2.qty then 'N'
        else 'Y' 
    end week_over_week_change,
    case 
        when t2.week is null or t1.qty = t2.qty then 'NA'
        else t1.qty - t2.qty 
    end week_over_week_change_qty
from table t1
left join table t2 on t2.prod = t2.prod and t2.week = t1.week + 1
```

Comment: Of course you can implement this - you need `LAG()`/`LEAD()` functionality

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse : ok, removed that part of my answer - meanwhile how do you like the suggested SQL query ?

Comment: You are responding to me (I deleted my objection after your edit). I don't like your SQL query; analytic functions were invented precisely to eliminate joins in such problems. That was a very long time ago.

Comment: I saw the SQL in your answer and I do see your point. May I just point out that my SQL would work on most RDBMS (as several tags were present in the question) ? But anyway, thank you for taking the time to clarify and demonstrate !

Answer (score 1):

Querying Excel directly:

```vb
Sub TestQuery()

    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sPath, t
    Dim sSQL As String, s As String

    sSQL = " select t1.*, t2.qty, IIf(t1.Qty=t2.Qty,'N','Y') as changed,  " & _
           " IIf(t1.Qty=t2.Qty,'NA',t2.qty-t1.qty) as change " & _
           " from [Sheet4$] t1, [Sheet4$] t2 " & _
           " where t1.Prod=t2.Prod and t2.Week = t1.week+1 "

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    oConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" & _
               "DBQ=" & sPath & ";"

    Set oRS = oConn.Execute(sSQL)

    If Not oRS.EOF And Not oRS.BOF Then
        ToSheet Sheet5.Range("A1"), oRS
    Else
        MsgBox "No records found"
    End If

End Sub

Sub ToSheet(rng, rs)
    Dim f, i
    i = 0
    rng.Resize(1000, 200).ClearContents
    For Each f In rs.Fields
        rng.Offset(0, i).Value = f.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next f
    rng.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

Input/output:

[image]

Comment: OP and future readers, to run this solution you will need a Windows install of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This is in Oracle, but using analytic functions which are standard. The syntax may be slightly different in other SQL products, but the syntax of the functions themselves should be the same. I also use a `case` expression, which is also standard.

```
select week, prod,
       case when qty != lag(qty) over (partition by prod order by week)
            then 'Y' else 'N' end as week_over_week_change,
       qty - lag(qty) over (partition by prod order by week) as weekly_qty_change
from   [your table, view, or whatever]
........
```